# Is there any way to see which line of code is being executed, without Breaking execution?

Tags: visual-studio, legacy-code

Long story short, I am debugging a big application which I didn't write. It is throwing an error when it runs on the server on which it is supposed to be run, so I am testing on my own machine with the debugger attached to see what happens.

It has thousands of lines of code, and has been running for a couple of hours now. I want to know which line of code is currently executing, so I can get a rough idea of how long is left, but I don't want to **Break All** as the code is...rickety.

Short of firing watchpoints all over the place in a *spray and pray* fashion, is there a non-invasive way to see which line of code is executing right now?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the idea. On recent processors the program probably executes thousands lines of code per second, how you wanna track which line is it now in? There is call stack and IntelliTrace and should be all you need to debug an app.

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek If I am debugging and click on **Break All**, the execution breaks at whatever line is being executed right now. Can I see which line is being executed right now, without breaking? I know this is probably changing rapidly and that's ok, but let's say I am on the 5,000th iteration of a loop, this could tell me which loop and where. I am asking if Visual Studio contains this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can show the currently executing line and call stack in the process.

Right-click a process, click Properties, and then click the Threads tab.

Comment: Good find; likely PE uses StackWalk64 internally, see also here for a programmatic implementation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack

Comment: Good find indeed, thanks very much, great article also.